# I can't import my module jar file in my new Project

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, jar

> ## I imported my existing project as a module in my new project. My existing project have many library (Jar)files and i can't use the jar in my new project

**This my new App build gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.clientdemo'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.clientdemo"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation project(path: ':Bp_A75')
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSojV.png)
}
```

**This is my existing project App Build gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplication.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


//    defaultConfig{
//        ndk{
//            abiFilter 'armeabi'
//        }
//    }

    sourceSets {
        main  {
            // Here is the path to your source code
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation files('libs/RUBY.jar')
    implementation files('libs/AppSdkAidl_buildBy_20220217.jar')
    implementation files('libs/tataSdkClient-noemv_20220114.jar')

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
```

I want to use my module jar file in my new project app

[I also added my Existing module name in settings.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kNnt.png)